# all titles in an array in my object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to push the title of my blog posts in the title array of my blogSummary object.

I created me a year with the month and the count of the blog posts in this month.

Now I want to have all my titles in the array of title in my object.

I just see thje last title and not all the other fields are empty. Dont know why.

// functions

```
function buildMonthInBlogSummary(blogPostOne, blogPostTwo) {
  var dateBlogPostOne = new Date(blogPostOne.createdAt);
  var dateBlogPostTwo = new Date(blogPostTwo.createdAt);
  if(dateBlogPostOne.getMonth()+1 === dateBlogPostTwo.getMonth()+1){
    counter++;
    var month = dateBlogPostOne.getMonth()+1;
    blogSummary['2013'][month.toString()] = {
      'count': counter,
      'title': []
    };
    // console.log(blogPostOne);
    console.log(blogPostOne.title);
    blogSummary['2013'][month.toString()].title[counter] = blogPostOne.title;
  }
}
```

// what I get when I see my object title

```
[ ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  'Der erste fucking blog eintrag mit whaaaaattt' ]
```

Comment: Why are you adding one to both sides of a comparison? They cancel out

Comment: where is counter defined/ initialised

Comment: It's difficult to see with all the odd scoping you have there.  Neither blogSummary nor counter are declared in your function scope, so without knowing what's outside the codebase it's tough to replicate the issue you're having.  However - try removing the "counter" and "count" property - you can append onto an array with .push( contents ) and then get the length of it with .length instead.  See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/LNnpv/

Answer (score 0):

Note that the { count, title } - Object for the month is overwritten for each new blogpost element for a given month. Maybe you consider one local iteration over all your posts and create and update the accumulated 'month'-entries inside that.